# Does anyone have a manual for this radio?

Tags: transmitter, resources, online-resources

I ordered this [JJRC JJPRO EM-16 2.4GHz 6CH AFHDS 2A Mode 2 RC Transmitter with Receiver Support P175 for RC Drone](https://www.banggood.com/JJRC-JJPRO-EM-16-2_4GHz-6CH-AFHDS-2A-Mode-2-RC-Transmitter-with-Receiver-Support-P175-for-RC-Drone-p-1724957.html?rmmds=search&cur_warehouse=CN) from banggood, and now I'm trying to figure out what the default settings are and how to program it. I did a bunch of google searches, but I cannot find any sort of manual or user's guide or even a youtube tutorial for this radio online.

Does anybody know where I can find a manual for this radio?

Comment: Huh. Looks like a *highly* simplified FlySky FS-i6 clone...

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it doesn't actually even have configurable settings. The LCD screen and navigation buttons from the FlySky FS-i6 design have been removed, so I don't know how configuration would wotk anyways.

Comment: If you're lucky there may be some switches for servo reversing and to enable v-tail or elevon mixing hidden in the battery compartment or under a flap somewhere, but otherwise it looks like an ordinary non-programable radio. They're fine, so long as you only fly one model, or trim the model rather than the transmitter - you can just turn servos around to reverse them, and you can buy plug-in mixers that go between the Rx and servos. If you fly multi-rotors, you may never need to upgrade but if you fly planes I'd plan for an upgrade in a year or so.

Comment: I also bought this receiver and transmitter and struggling to understand channel 1 (thinking it could be PPM?), did you work out how to read it in the end?

Comment: @MattHiscocks, I had a problem with it when I bought mine as well, but I never fixed it. I just switched out ch4 for ch1. You lose ailerons but at least you have a rudder. If you plan on flying for more than a hobby you should probably get a new controller rather than learn bad flight habits by flying on a weird controller. If you do figure out how to fix that, let me know, I definitely want to fix that problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the radio arrived, and I plugged in some servos and a motor and here's what I think everything is;

Ch1 is rudder, right stick right+left(I think, there was something weird with it)

Ch2 is elevator, right stick up+down

Ch3 was motor, left stick up+down

Ch4 was ailerons, left stick right+left

Ch5 and CH6 were switches